# C++ curl_easy_perform() inserts newline into response

Tags: c++, curl

I'm fetching 43182 chars long JSON from remote REST API using following code snippet:

```
string result_;

curl_easy_setopt(curlGET_, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, CURL_TIMEOUT);
curl_easy_setopt(curlGET_, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curlGET_, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, CURL_DEBUG_VERBOSE);
curl_easy_setopt(curlGET_, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &result_);
curl_easy_setopt(curlGET_, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);

static size_t WriteCallback(void *response,
                            size_t size,
                            size_t nmemb,
                            void *userp) noexcept
        {
            (static_cast<string*>(userp))->append(static_cast<char*>(response));
            return size * nmemb;
        };

curlStatusCode_ = curl_easy_perform(curlGET_);
```

What I get in `result_` is complete JSON but with newline character after character 31954:

[image: newline in JSON]

If I fetch same JSON in browser or command-line curl there is no newline character. How to fix this problem for "arbitrarily" long JSON or other generic response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From CURL [document](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) of the write callback:

> The data passed to this function will not be zero terminated!

The `response` in `WriteCallback` is not necessarily null terminated. So calling `append` by just casting it to `char*` will invoke undefined behavior. You have to pass the amount of data too in `append`.

`(static_cast<string*>(userp))->append(static_cast<char*>(response), size * nmemb)`